# Detecting failure in R integrate function

Tags: r, statistics, numerical-integration

I'm using the `integrate` function in R to integrate a reasonably simple 1-d integral on the domain 0 to 1.  It mostly works, but will fail if the integrand is too "spiky".  That is, if the function I'm integrating is mostly 0, except on a small sub-domain of (0,1).

I understand that such functions are hard to integrate, but the problem is that `integrate` doesn't produce an error, but will instead return the incorrect answer with high confidence.  As a reproducible example, consider the integration of the beta distribution on the unit domain.

```
integrate(dbeta,lower=0,upper=1,shape1=1000,shape2=1000)
```

will return `1` as it should.  However, if I increase the shape parameters enough (concentrate the density function more and more around 0.5), eventually it will break.  For example,

```
integrate(dbeta,lower=0,upper=1,shape1=10000000,shape2=10000000)
```

returns

```
6.95229e-20 with absolute error < 0
```

In this case I understand the integrand well enough to know when it becomes difficult and predict that `integrate` won't work.  But is there a general way to predict and flag when an integrand is problematic and the results of `integrate` unreliable as a result?

Comment: Check if the result equals zero (within floating point accuracy).

Comment: But no, there is no general way (or the function would apply it). Even a check for zero isn't sufficient. Your integrand could be a constant different from zero outside of the spike. Numeric integration will miss narrow spikes.

Comment: It would be expensive, but you could provide _some_ check (not fool-proof) by dividing the region into multiple pieces and adding the integrals over the pieces. Essentially,  that just changes the definition of what "narrow spike" means.

Comment: I don't know what the `integrate` function is doing; it seems likely that it's calling a standard library such as QUADPACK. Be that as it may, you might try calling QAGS (a QUADPACK function); QAGS applies Gaussian quadrature with subdivision. There is probably an interface for R.